# java code to search a file entire system, works fine on windows but infinite in linux ubuntu

Tags: java, linux

Developing search utility to search a file entire computer system, works fine on windows platform but becomes an infinite process in ubuntu linux. Please help to overcome this flaw. The following is the main part of the code.

```
public static void fun(File f){  // root directory is passed as argument
try{
   if(f.isDirectory()){
       File [] fi=f.listFiles();
       for(int i=0;i<fi.length;i++){
           if(fileFound==true) break;   // fileFound is boolean data type used as flag to indicate whether the file is found or not
           System.out.println(fi[i].getName());
           fun(fi[i]);
       }
   }
   else{
       if(f.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(txtFile.getText()) || 
         (f.getName().toLowerCase().startsWith(txtFile.getText().toLowerCase())) ||     
         (f.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(txtFile.getText().toLowerCase()))){    
           l.setText("file found " + f.getAbsolutePath()); // l is JLabel that indicated prints the info like file found and its path
           fileFound=true;
       }
   }
}
catch(Exception e){
}
}
```

Comment: Is it possible that your program enters some cyclic dependency due to symlinks? Also please remove empty catch and throw exception (maybe wrapped) instead.

Comment: Don't be so serious with people naming their methods "fun".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error you are observing may be due to nested [symbolic links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link).

The most effective approach to solve this problem would be to instead use [`FileUtils#iterateFiles`](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#iterateFiles%28java.io.File,%20org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.IOFileFilter,%20org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.IOFileFilter%29) from the excellent [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/) library.

Answer (score 3):

There is something like "." (current directory) and ".." (above directory) in each dir in linux. Maybe thats your problem.

Comment: there are some files like power,wakeup, wakeup_count,wakeup_active_count,....,runtime_status,control,etc. When control reaches this files the process becomes continuous and thus infinite.

Answer (score 0):

In unix like systems the first folder is "." (current folder)
and the second folder is ".." (the root folder)

you should skip the first 2 folders to avoid getting to the same folder over and over again.

try:

```
if(fi[i].getName() == "." || fi[i].getName() == "..")
    continue;
```

Comment: @user1176616: it is advisable to use `.equals()` method for string comparison.